# Angular and Database Access : Proper Practices

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I get the general idea at this point, angular.js is client-side, so any attempts to do database communication is done via initiating get/post requests to a server-side script on the server (via node, php, asp.net, whatever you're using)...

Only thing I haven't been able to determine is what's the proper practice for this in both conventions/security : do you make specialized pages for many of your particular queries, or 1 to a few general purpose pages that run whatever passed in as parameters. That latter option seems like a security nightmare but at the same time making a page for each table's select,insert,update, etc also seems nonviable.

To be clear and try and focus this back to a single question, it feels like I'm missing a concept here. How do you structure the database calls for an angular.js application?

Comment: For your particular queries on the server side, you can implement a RESTFul service: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer

Comment: If I'm understanding your question correctly, the concept you're missing is asynchronous requests (ajax). As far as app structure, you generally create a service to handle database communication.

In a nutshell: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#data-services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a security standpoint it isn't very different than a traditional web app. Your web server sends and receives json (most likely) instead of html. This means using something like [rails-api](https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api) instead of full rails. It's best to think of your Angular app as completely disconnected from your web server like an Android or iOS app is.

You might use [token based authentication](https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-ins-and-outs-of-token-based-authentication) instead of cookies (nothing would preclude you from using token based auth in a traditional web app but I wouldn't say it's commonplace in traditional web apps). Other than that any concepts that apply to securing a traditional web application apply to securing an API.

Answer (score 0):

What database do you use? Structure depends on the app you're building and if DB is relational or not. It's a strategic question, for example it may be better to have nested documents, or not.